# Copying Files between Instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-ssm

Is there a way to copy files directly between managed EC2 Instances?
Instances appear in Fleet Manager and the UI provides the option of copying files between drives on a single instance. But not between multiple instances.
Is this a supported process?

Answer (score 0):

I have same trouble, and one way I have seen is possible is to use S3 as an intermediary store between the 2 instances or even between the fleet manager instance and your PC. For this is necesary to use the internet browser inside the managed instance (origin file) and enter console user credentials with S3 permissions and the same for your PC or any other managed instance (destination instance).
Not very practical but works.